# subquery rules in the union function postgresql

Tags: postgresql, subquery, union

I want to make a report with results from different Tables

```
SELECT week, countA, countB
FROM (
 (SELECT week, COUNT(*) AS countA FROM dataA a
 GROUP BY 1 )
 UNION
 (SELECT week , COUNT(*) AS countB FROM dataB 
  WHERE blablabla ...  GROUP BY 1) b
  ) c
```

now I have some issues

- he don't want that the subquery b has a name
- he don't know what countB is, if I don't give the 2nd query a name
- I get confused and don't know if and where I should put the name for the 2nd query

Is their a solution for that and is their some kind of "rulebook" because I get confused every time I work with the UNION function

Comment: BTW: UNION is not a function. It is an operator (that glues together two table-expressions, yielding one table expression)

Comment: There is a "rulebook". It's called "the manual": https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT test, counter
  FROM (
    (SELECT test, COUNT(*) AS counter FROM tableA
     GROUP BY 1 )
    UNION
    (SELECT test , COUNT(*) AS counter FROM tableB 
    WHERE test <> 0  GROUP BY 1) 
   ) c
```

you not need to name the queries, union merge two tables with the same columns together. But it not merges two tables where the columns different. So you need the counters to name equal. So you have two columns test and counter from tableA and tableB.

Comment: yeah forgot that the Union function does that & and i relize that kinda task i have UNion isnt that usefull, but thank you very much for your answer

Comment: You don't actually need the columns of the second query in the union to have the same names as the first one. The column names of the result are only determined by the very first query.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this query by doing this:

```
SELECT test, COUNT(*) AS counter FROM tableA
 GROUP BY 1
UNION
SELECT test , COUNT(*) AS counter FROM tableB 
WHERE test <> 0  GROUP BY 1
```

The columns do not have to have the same name. As long as they are "union compatible" (in a nutshell, same types or types that can be promoted to each other). The name of the columns in the resulting table will be the same as in the first select query.